# Smart contract distribution

Tags: contract-invocation

I created a erc20 contract with a total supply of 40,000,000.
10 mil was sent to my wallet and 30 mil suppose to go to investors.

When someone invest, how can I send him tokens from my contract to his erc20 wallet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as ERC20 wallet, unless you have created your own.

The smart contract of your ERC20 token is a place where all tokens are and they are not travelling to other contracts and wallets. The way someone can actually have a number of tokens is just the the mapping usually called `balances` in which by query `balances[address]` you can receive `amount` of tokens this particular address hold.

---

> When someone invest, how can I send him tokens from my contract to his erc20 wallet?

You just update the state by executing something like:

```
balances[addr_of_investor] = amount_of_tokens;
```

Comment: Where do I do that? balances[addr_of_investor] = amount_of_tokens;

Comment: You will have to add this functionality to your contract, as it was just an example. For further read I suggest payable functions, fallback functions.

Comment: @Soher No, you don't.

Comment: Can I fix it if its already verified contract?

Comment: If the contract is deployed you can’t change it, but you still can make changes in your code and deploy a new one.